# Group By, SUM and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking for a solution to group and count. I have a working SQL which counts open records per value:

```
SELECT tech_query.assigned_to_group, COUNT(tech_query.assigned_to_group) AS qty
  FROM tech_query
 WHERE tech_query.status <> 9 
   AND tech_query.status <> 3
GROUP BY tech_query.assigned_to_group
ORDER BY tech_query.assigned_to_group
```

The outcome:

```
Name:           | qty
-----------------------
ME-MS           | 5
MU-TA-AAA       | 4
MU-TA-BBB       | 2
MU-TA-CCC       | 3
```

Now I also like to combine the `Name` data which begins with `MU%`, `sum` the data of this value `MU%` and get an outcome as follows:

```
Name:           | qty
-----------------------
ME-MS           | 5
MU              | 9
```

Curious if somebody can help :-)

Comment: A derived table, which returns MU or the "other" value.

Comment: Is the `MU` aggregation the only instance of this desired behavior?  I.e. for all other groups, do you plan to use the name as it already appears?

Answer (score 3):

You need contional for mu like. try this query:

```
SELECT (case when tech_query.assigned_to_group like "MU%" then "MU"
             else tech_query.assigned_to_group end) as Name,
       COUNT(tech_query.assigned_to_group) AS qty
  FROM tech_query
 WHERE tech_query.status <> 9 
   AND tech_query.status <> 3
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table to extract `MU` part when required:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS qty
FROM
(select case when tech_query.assigned_to_group like 'MU%' then 'MU'
             else tech_query.assigned_to_group end as name
 from tech_query
 WHERE tech_query.status <> 9 
   AND tech_query.status <> 3) dt
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

**Note**: When reading the other answer (Balinti's), I realize MySQL perhaps wants double quotes for string literals, instead of ANSI SQL's single quotes? So maybe you need to replace  `'MU%' then 'MU'` with `"MU%" then "MU"`?

Comment: Great! Thank you jarlh :-) and ofcourse the others for replying